# Set user agent for HTTP request in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, user-agent

I'm writing a Chrome extension in pure JavaScript and wish to change the user agent for HTTP requests to a given URL as the owner of that URL has requested that a user agent of a certain format be used.

The following code works until the user agent modification line is added, at which point the Chrome inspector console give the error `Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"`.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", serviceURL, true, username, password);
xhr.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'MyExtensionName/0.0.1');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // do some stuff
}
xhr.send(null);
```

Why is it not possible to modify the user agent in this manner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot set that heading in a request of that kind, the browser will block it - along with many other header types.

In a Chrome extension however you can use [chrome.webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) to alter headers.

This will adjust a User Agent. Change  to your desired URL, following the [Match Patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) guidelines. Remember to add permissions for webRequest and webRequestBlocking to your manifest.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){
    for(var i=0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i){
        if(details.requestHeaders[i].name === "User-Agent"){
            details.requestHeaders[i].value = "Desired User Agent Here";

            break;
        }
    }
    return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
```